# Need help having a particular setup for vsftp with virtual users with access to a particular folder

Tags: ubuntu, file-permissions, ftp, chroot

as part of some services we are offering to some companies, we have gradually became the hosting providers for them using amazon services. so we host 2 web sites on amazon. the root documents for the website are : `/var/www/vhosts/{comp1.com, comp2.com}` .

so company 1 wanted to have access to their files so I created a virtual user on `vsftpd` using this tutorial from [www.sigerr.org](http://www.sigerr.org/linux/setup-vsftpd-custom-multiple-directories-users-accounts-ubuntu-step-by-step) (which is by the way the clearest and simplest I have seen so far). So i got it working no problem I can connect etc with chroot.

```
 -comp1.com  // same for comp2.com with chmod set to 555 and chown by root:root
    +htdocs
    +logs
```

Now the client from company 1 says he doesn't want his Not so IT personel to tamper with files so they only want access to `htdocs/Images` or `htdocs/somefolder/Images` (can't remember).

what options do I have? I thought of having a hybrid setup with both virtual and local users where local user's home will be `/var/www/vhosts/comp1.com/htdocs/Images` but am still unsure of how to go about it.

Can anyone suggest any solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to follow the same logic to i created a new virtual user images.comp1.com and created its folder in the vhosts folder:

```
# mkdir /var/www/vhosts/images.comp1.com
# mkdir /var/www/vhosts/images.comp1.com/images
```

I later added the privileges and owner as per the tutorial.

```
#chwown root:root  /var/www/vhosts/images.comp1.com
#chmod 555  /var/www/vhosts/images.comp1.com
#chown -R vsftpd:nogroup  /var/www/vhosts/images.comp1.com/images
```

after failed trials of doing symbolic links, with little search I realized found out that `mount --bind` is my best friend in this case. so I did the following

```
# mount --bind /var/www/vhosts/comp1.com/htdocs/images   /var/www/vhosts/images.comp1.com/images
```

And so far so good.

THanks for everything

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to switch to more flexible FTP server like [Pure-ftpd](http://www.pureftpd.org/project/pure-ftpd/doc), where you can configure virtual users with the chroot dir access you want and set up uid and gid virtually.

[howto with mysql for Ubuntu](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-hosting-with-pureftpd-and-mysql-ubuntu-7.10)